# Laptop webcam always shows video upside down

Tags: windows-7, drivers, webcam, camera

I have an integrated webcam (USB 2.0 UVC 2M) on my laptop. Whenever I turn it on for video conferencing either on Skype or Google Talk, it always shows upside down.

I am not sure what is wrong with the configuration. I have not installed any driver for it. Whatever software that comes bundled with the OS is what it has at the moment.

Is there any configuration changes or drivers that I need to install?

I would also prefer installing some software for video capture from webcam and the possibility to edit as well.

Comment: You could always turn your laptop upside down. :)

Comment: Well.. I dont do that.. I stand upside down whenever I am doing videoconferencing .. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem, particularly with ASUS and Lenova products, and is almost always a driver issue. Nine times out of ten, simply updating the camera's driver by going to your computer's manufacturer's website and manually downloading and installing it will make the problem go away.

If you happen to be one of the unlucky few for whom this doesn't work you'll need to either instruct each application to rotate the image or, if you're feeling adventurous, remove the monitor's faceplate and physically turn the camera. A caveat though about that last option is that a later driver update may well flip it again.

As to your second question, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is, in my opinion, the best all around product for capturing webcam video. It's not the absolute best in any one function but it does do a little bit of everything.

Comment: Thanks, I installed Camera_Azurewave_VS010 Software. I suppose the Webcam driver, which I downloaded from the ASUS website and after the reboot worked like a charm, Give a High-Five, Vow..  _|||| :)

Comment: I used to be a Lenovo service tech. I was told by someone higher-up once that Lenovo actually installs its cameras upside-down relative to how other OEMs put them in, which is why generic drivers will result in upside-down video, while the Lenovo-issued drivers flip it. My personal Asus has the same issue. Not sure why these two manufacturers do this.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a device driver issue. You need to find the chipset device drivers for your laptop. http://www.driverstorer.com/drivers.html is a good place to start. In the unlikely event your webcam was installed upside down, you may be in trouble =)

Answer (score -1):

I was actually able to fix this issue (with windows 7) by going into the display settings, and there was a box for "landscape flipped".  It seemed the problem was not the camera, it was the display.